# How to add a default for datetime datatype in memsql

Tags: singlestore

I want to create a table in `memsql` with one of the column as `datetime` and its value will be current date-time. I tried giving `now()`,`current_time()` and `current_date()` as default value but nothing is working

```
singlestore> create table y (col2 datetime default now());
ERROR 1067 (42000): Invalid default value for 'col2'
```

OR

```
singlestore> create table y (col2 datetime default current_timestamp());
ERROR 1067 (42000): Invalid default value for 'col2'
```

OR

```
singlestore> create table y (col2 datetime default current_date());
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'current_date())' at line 1
```

Version `Server version: 5.5.58 MemSQL source distribution (compatible; MySQL Enterprise & MySQL Commercial)`

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

That is the right syntax.  Which version of SinglestoreDB are you using ?

```
singlestore [test]> create table y (col2 datetime default now());
Query OK, 0 rows affected (1.691 sec)
```

edit: This requires a I believe at least version 7.0 of SinglestoreDB.  Older versions only support default now() on timestamp columns and not datetime.

Comment: thanks for the answer I have added my version in question, I think it is 5.5

Comment: What does "select @@memsql_version" show?  The 5.5 will be the MySQL compat. version.   As far as I know, even very old versions of MemSQL/Singlestore support this syntax though.

Comment: oh yeah, its "6.7.29"

Comment: The problem is the older version of SinglestoreDB your running.  It only support DEFAULT NOW() for TIMESTAMP columns (not DATETIME).   You'll need to upgrade to a newer version if you need it for a DATETIME column.